# calling javascript output in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

hi everyone i want to create a dropdown menu to select time. And i used javascript to get the time of the computer. then, i want to have an output if the the time of the computer is equal to the value of dropdown menu then the output should be selected. 
below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function time(){ 
var currentTime = new Date();
$hours = currentTime.getHours();
document.write($hours);
}
</script>       
<select>
<?php $hr="<script>time();</script>";//calling the output from javascript
for($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++): ?>
<option value="<?= $i; ?>" <?if ($i==$hr) echo "selected";?> > 
<?= $i % 12 ? $i % 12 : 12 ?>   <?= $i >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am' ?>   
</option>
<?php endfor ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to start from the basics and learn how php and javascript work.

Comment: Your PHP is going to be interpreted on the server side, which will happen prior to the client side (web user) has a chance to interpret. Thus, your PHP won't work there. What you're trying to do should be possible using only JavaScript.

Comment: this is an awful antipattern, avoid this at all costs

Comment: Most... common... question... everrrr

Comment: To provide some content to what zerkms said, I suggest you start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side scripting language and Javascript is a client side scripting language. When the user views your web page, the php code would already have been executed. So you cannot mix and match the languages and try to use the output of JS intermixed with PHP without a form return or a passback (with or without XHR)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by not outputting javascript in your php scripts. This is not easy to create, read or maintain.

I've only ever dipped only my toes in php and know very little about php specifics, but depending on what, if any framework you are using, you should try and abstract out as much of the view (client side markup/script) out of your php logic. Templating engines are your friend!

If I were you I would look into a framework like codeigniter or cakePHP. These are designed to make your life easier, although over time you will find you may not agree with many of the decision they make for you.

Having said that, I think it's important and start with the basics, like zerkms mentioned. Know what each layer of a web application is responsible for. You will only give yourself a headache if you try and produce client sides scripts from within your php.